# How to write this postgres sql query to oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Following is the postgres SQL query which i have used. I need to change this query to run in Oracle.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id,
                d.title,
                d.entityname,
                d.abstract,
                d.url,
                d.ranking,
                d.forwardemail,
                d.technologyclass,
                d.technology,
                d.product,
                d.technologytype,
                d.comments,
                d.status,
                d.year,
                d.day,
                d.month,
                d.entitytype,
                d.entitysource,
                d.chapter,
                d.country,
                d.region,
                d.address
FROM   research_data d
WHERE  d.status = 'A'
       AND d.id IN(SELECT e.parent_id
                   FROM   research_data_history e
                   WHERE  e.changed_date::DATE = To_date('02-01-13', 'MM-DD-YY'))
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? What did you get up to? Where are you stuck? Seems like a pretty straightforward query.

Comment: What data type is `research_data_history.changed_date`? And what is the purpose of the cast to `date`? If you want to remove the time from a timestamp use `trunc()` in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? Are you getting an error when running it in Oracle? You should only have to remove ::DATE from the sub select.

```
SELECT
  e.parent_id
FROM
  research_data_history e
WHERE
  e.changed_date = to_date('02-01-13', 'MM-DD-YY')
```